# Modulos Counter

Tags: java, count, counter, modulo

I have a few questions. I am new to java and am curious how to go about creating a modulus counter. Starting out I have a Driver class and a Counter class.

My counter class is:

```
public class Counter {

private int count;
private int modulo;

public Counter () {
    count = 0;
    this.modulus= (count + 1)%8;
  }

public int currentCount () {
    return count;
  }

public void incrementCount () {
    count = count + 1;
  }

public void reset () {
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

I added the modulus constructor, but I'm confused on how to implement it in my driver class. Any input helps. Thanks!

NEW COUNTER

```
public class Counter_01 {

  private int count;
  private int x;

  public Counter_01 (int x) {
    this.count = x;
    this.x = x;
  }

  public void incrementCount () {
    count = (count + 1) % x;
  }

  public int currentCount () {
    return count;
  }

  public void reset () {
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

NEW DRIVER

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args){

int count; 
    Counter myCounter = newCounter(x);

do {
    if (myCounter.currentCount() <=10){
     count = myCounter.incrementCount();
}
      else {
      myCounter.reset();
}
    } while (count < 11);
}
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what output do you expect... argument your question with any example!

Comment: I want the out put to be something like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1     Basically the count resets when the mod value is reached

Comment: so why do you need a class for this? Just use a for loop and print the modulo of its index variable

Comment: Its part of our assignment (we have to use a counter and driver class). Ill show you my driver class that Ive been working on.

Comment: I think you will need a getter for `modulo` variable since its modifier is private. Then in the constructor the variable `modulus` it is never declared.